# modify $http code into promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise, angular-http

This is the code I working on.

```
  appControllers.controller('MyaSellerOrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Order', '$http',
        function($scope, $rootScope, Order, $http) {
            $scope.results = [];
            $scope.getData = function() {
                   $http.get('api/orders/business/?user_id=' + $rootScope.user.user_id).success(function(data){
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $http.get('api/orders/seller/?business_id=' + data[i].business_id).success(function(data1){
                                 // console.log(data1);        
                                 $scope.results[i] = data1;
                           });
                         }
                         console.log($scope.results);
                    });
             };
             $scope.getData();
         }]);
```

The problem is that $scope.results is empty while the functions works properly. Some one has told that it is due to the asynchronous nature of $http. Can you modify the code to use promise to avoid error ?

Now i updated the code as shown

```
appControllers.controller('MyaSellerOrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http','$q',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $q) {

        $scope.results = [];

        function _getOrdersById(id) {
            return $http.get('api/orders/business/?user_id=' + id);
        }

        function _parseOrders(orders) {
            var _promises = [];

            orders.forEach(function (order, index) {
                var _promise = $http.get('api/orders/seller/?business_id=' + order.business_id).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.results[index] = response;
                });

                _promises.push(_promise);
            });

            return $q.all(_promises);
        }

        $scope.getData = function () {
            _getOrdersById($rootScope.user.user_id)
                .then(_parseOrders)
                .then(function () {
                    console.log($scope.results);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        };


        $scope.getData();

    }
]);
```

but it still shows error

[image: console output]

159 line points to the line

```
orders.forEach(function(order,index) {
```

Comment: $http is already a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use case, the `console.log($scope.results)` comes in too early.

If you did the "proper way" or this "don't do it at home 'cause it's stupid" way, you'd get the results.

**Incorrect** way to do it, just here to show you:

```
    var MyCtrl = app.controller(function($scope, $timeout, $http, $rootScope) {
        $scope.results = [];
        $scope.getData = function() {
               $http.get('api/orders/business/?user_id=' + $rootScope.user.user_id).success(function(data){
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $http.get('api/orders/seller/?business_id=' + data[i].business_id).success(function(data1){
                             // console.log(data1);        
                             $scope.results[i] = data1;
                       });
                     }

                     // THIS is the part I'm changing:
                     $timeout(function() {

                         console.log($scope.results);
                     }, 10000);
                });
         };
         $scope.getData();
     });
```

Just assuming here, but I think this should work. Why? Because we're logging the result after 10 seconds, when all the individual orders have been fetched.

Your version called the `console.log()` right away, before any of the `$http` requests for individual orders have been completed.

Slightly better way would be to do the `$q.all()` as others have suggested. And even better way would be to move this all to a service.

**Slightly better** way to do your thing:

```
// Controller. Notice how simplified it seems now, comparing to the original
// version. We're just passing results to and from the $scope, which is what
// controllers should do. 

var MyController = app.controller(function($scope, OrderService, $rootScope) {

    OrderService.getOrders($rootScope.user.user_id)
    .then(function(results) {

        // only putting $scope.results live here, you can have
        // an ng-show="$scope.results.length" or something to show a spinner
        // or similar while loading.
        $scope.results = results;
    });
});

// Then, your service would do all the work

var OrderService = app.service(function($http) {

    // we're going to play it with a service, just copy/pasting Lowe's answer here
    // and modifying a few bits to take out controller part

    var _results = [];

    // This returns a promise. Angular can accept a promise and will wait until resolved.
    function _getOrdersById(id) {
        return $http.get('api/orders/business/?user_id=' + id);
    }

    // This also returns a promise.
    function _parseOrders(orders) {
        var _promises = [];

        orders.forEach(function (order, index) {
            var _promise = $http.get('api/orders/seller/?business_id=' + order.business_id).then(function (response) {
                _results[index] = response;
            });

            _promises.push(_promise);
        });

        return $q.all(_promises);
    }

    // Anything attached to _this_ is "public" for a service
    this.getOrders = function(userId) {

        // Create a defered object to return to callers
        var d = $q.defer();

        // Get that first promise
        _getOrdersById(userId)

        // the next promise in order (_parseOrders), will receive whatever
        // _getOrdersById return
        .then(_parseOrders)

        // The next promise won't be called until $q.all of _parseOrders is called.
        .then(function () {

            // finally resolve our original promise. This returns to
            // the caller of the service
            d.resolve(_results);

        }, function (error) {

            console.error(error);
            d.reject(error);
        }); 

        // this return happens almost before any of the $http calls above.
        // But since you're returning a promise, angular knows this it have to wait
        // until that d.resolve() or d.reject() somewhere in the async response handlers. 
        return d.promise;

    });
```

There are probably even better ways to break this down, but you'd have to ask a bit more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is the fact that you are immediately trying to grab the data with the statement `console.log($scope.results);`. I suggest you read up on what asynchronous programming really is, as it will help you better understand why this is happening. `$http` already returns an `HttpPromise` according to the AngularJS documentation (which is just a modified promised) so there's no point changing that.

The thing is, making that `$http` call takes time, and you're iterating over it with a for loop (which is bad practice you should consider `$q.all()`). If you only have experience with synchronous programming, you might think that the `console.log($scope.results);` will happen once the for loop is complete, but that's not true. The calls in the for loop will go asynchronous, and you will be logging before you even get an answer back.

TL;DR : You really need to research the concept of asynchronous javascript and you're logging the variable before even getting a response back from the server :)

```
appControllers.controller('MyaSellerOrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Order', '$http', '$q',
function($scope, $rootScope, Order, $http, $q) {
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.getData = function() {
        $http.get('api/orders/business/?user_id=' + $rootScope.user.user_id)
            .success(function(data){

            var promises = data.map(function (item) {
                return $http.get('api/orders/seller/?business_id=' + item.business_id);
            });

            $q.all(promises).then(function(data) {

                //Use this to see what the data is
                console.log(data);
                //Add some logic here if data isn't exactly the array you want
                $scope.results = data;

            }, function (err) {
                //Do some error handling
            });

        });
     };
     $scope.getData();
}]);
```

Comment: I understand the success is asynchronous. But i need the success function to work synchronous with the each iteration.  How would i do that so that i get output for console for each iteration

Comment: I would definitely suggest looking into `$q.all` as I stated. If you implement it correctly, you'll be able to do some logic on every iteration, as well as get a total final result (It depends on your needs though so it's hard to give a general example).

Comment: So just to make things clear, do you want it so that all the requests are made, and then you have an array of all the responses?

Comment: @riyas_tk I've updated my post to include a solution to your code. Please try it out and play around with it as it would most likely be close to what you're looking for. Beware: I haven't tested it so some syntax errors may occur. Make sure to inject `$q` into your controller as I have above.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest promises to keep things a bit more stuctured. Since you want to do first one api-call and once that finishes one more per row in the results you also need to use the $q service, like Christopher mentions.

I have not tested this code but it hopefully gives you some idea of what I'm talking about.

```
$scope.results = [];

function _getOrdersById(id) {
    return $http.get('api/orders/business/?user_id=' + id);
}

function _parseOrders(orders) {
    var _promises = [];

    // Stop parsing if orders isn't an array
    if (!angular.isArray(orders)) {
        return;
    }

    orders.forEach(function (order, index) {
        var _promise = $http.get('api/orders/seller/?business_id=' + order.business_id).then(function (response) {
            $scope.results[index] = response;
        });

        _promises.push(_promise);
    });

    return $q.all(_promises);
}

$scope.getData = function () {
    _getOrdersById($rootScope.user.user_id)
        .then(_parseOrders)
        .then(function () {
            console.log($scope.results);
        }, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
};
```

Comment: I have updated the post with modification and error.

Comment: Whats on line 159 in checkoutController.js? What version of AngularJs are you using?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you put that into the post :) If you log out the "orders" variable, is it an Array - even if the endpoint does not return any results?